# Try-Catch not working in TestComplete

Tags: javascript, try-catch, testcomplete

In test complete I am trying to use a try-catch block to see if a message box has an okay button and then click the okay button without crashing. I put the click operation inside a try block so if it fails the catch block can deal with the error, but it is crashing inside the try block. Here's an example:

```
try
{
    okayButton = SomeLocation;
    okayButton.click();
}
catch(err)
{
    do something;
}
```

I would think that when Test Complete can't click the okay button, it would move into the catch block. However, I get an error on the okayButton.click(); line, which stops the test run. It says "there was an attempt to preform an action on a zero-sized window.". Does anyone know how do deal with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `okayButton.click();` does not `throw` an `err`, Your `catch` block will never be executed. You should validate that when `okayButton.click();` fails, it throws the error your `catch` block is expecting.

It may be that `okayButton.click();` is returning the error instead of throwing it.

Comment: that makes some sense, but how would I check weather okayButton.click(); is throwing or returning an error? And if it is returning an error is there a way I can make it throw the error instead?